# scroll the background farther than half the picture

Tags: home-screen, wallpaper, nokia-6

Is there a way to let android scroll 1080px through the wallpaper to show one of the pictures every page instead of half of the picture?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSW91.jpg)
I want every page to be a different picture,so it has to scroll 1080 pixels to the right instead of part of one picture and another half of the other when i go to the 2nd page. I tried some apps for that but apps like five wallpapers stutter and lag too much.
The wallpaper I use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umVlq.jpg