# How to properly set the Scrolling Wallpaper?

Tags: wallpaper, redmi

I've set a scrolling wallpaper, but it only accepted 2/3 of the complete image. I've seen some google apps whose wallpapers are 16:9 aspect ratio and still don't overlap and move from extreme left to extreme right. So how can I do the same with my own wallpaper?

And not only the app, If I apply a theme, the wallpaper in that theme also doesn't overlap and moves from extreme left to right.

[Refer these images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INcEs.jpg) to see what the app is capable of doing, and what happens when I try to do the same with my edited wallpaper. The app in talk is [Wallpapers of The Witcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mcmobile.wwp&hl=en_IN)

Using Redmi Note 5 Pro. Other specific details of the phone in screenshot included in the above imgur link.

First time posting here. I've asked this question at 3 different sites with 0 response. I hope I'll get some answer here. I know what I want is possible as the apps are capable of doing so. Also, I found [one question asked before](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/193333/scroll-the-background-farther-than-half-the-picture) with the same thing asking, but it isn't answered. Coincidentally, the previous asker wanted to apply the same wallpaper that I'm interested in.

Thank you.

PS: The art is not mine. It is from Deviantart artist astoralexander.

Answer (score 0):

The image does not seem to be matching the width of your screen. You need an image that is 3 times (exactly 3,240 pixels wide, according to this https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_5_pro-8893.php).

What is the width of your image? Of each part?

Comment: I added black bars to the image to make it 16:9, actual dimensions 4608x2592 pixels. But If I'm being logical, Such problem should only occur if the image is larger than the screen size and not smaller. It is logical to think the image will cropped as the image might be larger than the screen. But here it's the opposite.

EDIT: Ohhh sorry, it is large indeed. Let me reduce the size and check again.

Comment: Thank you for replying btw. I tried resizing the wallpaper, 3240x2160. But it still overlaps and shows only the first two images. The second screens have first and second images sharing half of each. The third image doesn't even show up.

Comment: I have tried 2160x1440 and 1080x720. Both are not working as well.